# Changing field values with ArcPy update cursor?

Tags: python, arcgis-10.3, cursor

I want to figure out how to be able to change values in fields for use in further projects. Right now , I would like to be able to add '-WA' to the existing field value 53. (ie 53-WA). This is a test project as I am trying to teach myself python. The code I got so far runs but the values do not change.

```
import arcpy, os

arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\Users\david.fleck\Python.mdb'

fc= 'Parking_Lots_Collected_2015'

field = ['STATEFP']

cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc,field)

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,field)as cursor:

    for row in cursor:
        if row== 53:
            row.setValue(row.getValue(field) + '-WA')
            cursor.updateRow(row)

print "Finished"
```

I have also tried `row ==''53 + '-CA'` instead of row.setvalue but still no change.

Comment: @Barbarossa shows a good way, but just for reference, a couple of problems with your code is that you set cursor twice (with statement usually better), and you're missing a space between '(fc, field)' and 'as'. as well as between 'row' and '=='. And if row is a text field, you need quotes around 53. If it's not a text field, you can't append text to it.

Answer (score 11):

Try the following:

```
import arcpy, os
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\Users\david.fleck\Python.mdb'

fc= 'Parking_Lots_Collected_2015'
field = ['STATEFP']

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,field) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] == '53':
            row[0] = row[0] + '-WA'
            cursor.updateRow(row)

print "Finished"
```

Note that this will only work if STATEFP is a text field.

Comment: Might need to put the 53 in quotes, assuming it is a text field.

Comment: Correct.  See edits.

Answer (score 1):

To provide a contrast to @Barbarossa's answer.  Here is how it is done using the other arcpy update cursor.  I adjusted things a little bit to simplify some python code.

I find when learning/explaining arcpy cursors, to save the `da` cursors for later after you get a hold of this version.  **This version is slower and less powerful**, but it is pretty simple to grasp.

```
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = r'C:\Users\david.fleck\Python.mdb'

with arcpy.UpdateCursor('Parking_Lots_Collected_2015') as rows:
  for row in rows:
    if row.STATEFP == '53':
      row.STATEFP += '-WA'
      rows.updateRow(row)

print "Finished"
```

It seems ESRI has changed some code samples to use the `with` statement.  Since you're learning, you may run across other samples using a different way to accomplish the same thing.

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\Users\david.fleck\Python.mdb'

rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor('Parking_Lots_Collected_2015')
for row in rows:
  if row.STATEFP == '53':
    row.STATEFP = row.STATEFP + '53'
    rows.updateRow(row)

del row
del rows
print "Finished"
```

Hopefully both samples along with @Barbarossa's answer provide some contrast for you.  Being newer with python, if you don't understand some of the different ways things were done here, **please comment** to get an explanation.  Either that or Dr. Google works wonders.